# Return Future on Event

Tags: java, spring, future

I am looking for a suitable solution for the following problem.

My component is receiving a message and publishes it to a distributed system. The original sender is expecting an acknowledgment, that the message was processed.

I am receiving a confirmation that the message was processed (via RabbitMQ) when the message went through the whole system, but have to block till I get this confirmation.

This is the code blocking for the response of the listener class.

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> messageReceived = listenerClass.isMessageReceivedMatching(identifier);
boolean messageConfirmation = messageReceived.join();
if(messageConfirmation) {
    sendMessagePorcessedConfirmationToOrigin();
}
```

The listener class extends classes handling the logic to receive the message from RabbitMQ.

```
private Message message;

/**
*  Receives the message when it passed through the whole system.
*/
@Override
protected void receive(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public CompletableFuture<Boolean> isMessageReceivedMatching(identifier) {
    //wait till a new message is received and the message is not null
    //match identifier and message
    //set message field back to null
}
```

I really looking to avoid creating a while loop waiting until the message comes in. Alternatively:

- `ApplicationEventPublisher` and listening for specific events which seems also not the right solution.
- Springs `ListenableFuture` was also pointed out to might be helpful here... but I am not sure how to use it here.

Thanks for the help or any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is now the solution I ended up with ... I wrapped the message in a `CompletableFuture` and `.complete()` it when the message comes in over the `receive()` method.

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> messageReceived = listenerClass.isMessageReceivedMatching(identifier);
boolean messageConfirmation = messageReceived.join();
if(messageConfirmation) {
    sendMessagePorcessedConfirmationToOrigin();
}
```

```
private CompletableFuture<Boolean> matchingMessage;
private String identifier;

@Override
protected void receive(Incident message) {
    if (omsIdentifier == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (matches(identifier)) {
        //if not already completed, sets the value
        matchingMessage.complete(true);
    } 
}

CompletableFuture<Boolean> isMessageReceivedMatching(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    matchingMessage = new CompletableFuture<>();
    return matchingMessage;
}
```